# TypeScript: type alias vs string-based enum

Tags: typescript

So, I've got:

```js
interface Foo {
  type: FooType;
}
```

Which one is better to be used as `FooType` here:

**Type alias**?

```js
type FooType = 'BAR' | 'BAZ';
```

Or **string-based enum**?

```js
enum FooType {
  BAR = 'BAR',
  BAZ = 'BAZ'
}
```

What are the pros and cons of the two?

Answer (score 4):

Your first example (which you call a "type alias") is actually called a [string literal type](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/types/literal-types.html).

I think it's down to personal preference.

***enums***

- **Pro** you don't need to know what the internal value is
- **Pro** (subjective) the code reads well
- **Con** they have runtime artifacts (although you can use `const enum` to avoid this)
- **Con** they cannot be ambient

***string literal***

- **Pro** no runtime artifacts (and it can be ambient)
- **Pro** no need to pass around the value

  - **Con** when dealing with `string` typed values, you usually have to assert to `any` before asserting to your value

```js
let x: string
let y: FooType

y = x as any as FooType
```

(**edit**: hmm, looks like they fixed this)

I used to prefer enums, but lately I've been leaning towards string literal types. Again, I think it all comes down to personal preference.

Comment: just my 2c: ambient enums are [supported](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html#ambient-enums).

Comment: Sure, but because enums have a runtime artifact, you _also_ have to already have defined that enum elsewhere: "Ambient enums are used to describe the shape of already existing enum types."

Comment: the most important pro of enums for me is the better support in IDEs: e.g. **refactoring** and of couse **finding references**